# Given points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lying on a circle and lines $BD$ and $AC$ intersecting at $F$, prove lines are parallel

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles, circles, tangent-line

[image: I want help in part 1 and 3 only]

The diagram shows the points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lying on a circle. $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at point $F$. $EG$ is tangent to the circle at point $C$. $AD$ is produced to meet the tangent at point $E$. Given that $\angle{ABC} = \angle{BFC}$ prove that $BD \parallel EG$.

In part 1, we need to prove lines are parallel, which means we can show angles $\angle{AFB} = \angle{FCB}$ (corresponding angles), $\angle{AFB} = \angle{FCE}$ (alternate angles), $\angle{AFB} + \angle{CFB} = 180^{\circ}$ The problem is line segment $CA$ is not a radius (it's not mentioned in the question) so we can not say $CA$ is perpendicular. Then how do we find those angles and equate it ??
I also tried to apply exterior angle property on triangle on triangle $\triangle AFB$ ($\angle{BFC} = \angle{FAB} + \angle{FBA}$) but didn't get anything.

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Hint: Use alternate segment theorem.

Comment: if i apply alternate seg theorem then angle BCG=FAB ??

Comment: @TalhaAhmed: Yes

Comment: I still couldn't find a way to prove  :(

Answer (score 3):

[image: BD parallel to EG]

Since $\angle ABC=\angle BFC$, and $\angle BCA$ is common to both triangles, then$$\triangle ABC\sim\triangle BFC$$and$$\angle CAB=\angle FBC$$

And by the alternate segment theorem$$\angle CAB=\angle BCG$$Therefore$$\angle FBC=\angle BCG$$and hence$$BD\parallel EG$$

Comment: thankyou ! I understand now

Answer (score 0):

Since $\angle BFC=\frac{\overset{\huge\frown}{AD}+\overset{\huge\frown}{BC}}{2}$ and $\angle ABC=\frac{\overset{\huge\frown}{AD}+\overset{\huge\frown}{DC}}{2}$ where measure of arcs are read from the center and $\angle BFC=\angle ABC$, we have $\overset{\huge\frown}{BC}=\overset{\huge\frown}{DC}$ which means that $\angle BDC=\angle DCE$ and $DB\parallel EG$.